# Show new matplotlib graph further down Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm learning `Matplotlib` and using a Jupyter notebook to track each thing that I learn. However, I ran into a problem because I have multiple cells with `matplotlib` code. In one of my first cells, I run `plt.show()`, which outputs a plot beneath the cell. Further down the page, I have some other code which plots new points, resizes an axis, etc., then runs `plt.show()`....which works, but applies the changes to the original plot that was created after the first cell.

Is there any way to get a new plot window to display beneath whichever cell I am running?

(The reason I want to do this: The first cell might be an example showing how to plot a basic set of points. I want this to display its own simple plot. Further down the page, I resize axes and change the style of graph. However, when this plots, I want to see a separate plot, or maybe the same plot redone (as in, it can keep the original points I plotted -- no need to clear the whole thing) but with the new changes, beneath this more complex cell.)

UPDATE: Images.

In Image 1, I have run the first cell of code. The graph displays beneath the cell. Just as I want.
[image]

In this second image, I've now run the lower block of code (marked `[3]`). The changes, however, are applied to the plot sitting above it, because that's where it was originally created. But I'd like a new plot, or maybe not a clean new plot, but at least some way to make that plot display beneath cell `[3]` that I just ran.
[image]

Comment: That worked! Interesting. I originally made it `%matplotlib notebook` because that allows interactivity. However, it appears interactivity gives this behavior, because the original plot can still update. Therefore, rather than make a new plot beneath each code block, it simply updates the original plot. I was able to get it to work using both your solution, or, using `%matplotlib notebook`, by adding the line `plt.ioff()`. Wish there was a way to have interactivity with a new plot, though. Any way to force a new plot?

Comment: You're awesome. That worked, thank you!

Comment: Do you want to just answer it so I can mark this?

Comment: Possibly relevant here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45760693/how-to-overlay-plots-from-different-cells

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the comments, you mentioned that you're using the `%matplotlib notebook` magic, because it allows interactivity.

One option is to stop using interactivity.

As you found, you can turn off interactivity with `plt.ioff()`.  You could also stop using `%matplotlib notebook` altogether and instead use `%matplotlib inline` (called at the top of the notebook).  With `%matplotlib inline`, you don't need to call `plt.show()`.

But you want to use interactivity.

So what you should do is define a new figure after you've plotted your first figure.  To do this, call `plt.figure()` after the first plot, before the code for the second.