# How to overlay plots from different cells?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

In one of the cells in my notebook, I already plotted something with

`myplot = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y)`

Now, in a different cell, I'd like to plot the exact same figure again, but add new plots on top of it (similar to what happens with two consecutive calls to `plt.plot()`). What I tried was adding the following in the new cell:

`myplot
 plt.plot(xnew,ynew)`

However, the only thing I get in the new cell is the new plot, without the former one.

How can one achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are essentially two ways to tackle this.

#### A. Object-oriented approach

Use the object-oriented approach, i.e. keep handles to the figure and/or axes and reuse them in later cells.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

fig, ax=plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1,2,3])
```

Then in a later cell,

```
ax.plot([4,5,6])
```

Suggested reading:

- [How to keep the current figure when using ipython notebook with %matplotlib inline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31441247/how-to-keep-the-current-figure-when-using-ipython-notebook-with-matplotlib-inli)
- [How to add plot commands to a figure in more than one cell, but display it only in the end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44118059/how-to-add-plot-commands-to-a-figure-in-more-than-one-cell-but-display-it-only)
- [How do I show the same matplotlib figure several times in a single IPython notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36265987/how-do-i-show-the-same-matplotlib-figure-several-times-in-a-single-ipython-noteb)

#### B. Keep figure in pyplot

The other option is to tell the matplotlib inline backend to keep the figures open at the end of a cell.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

%config InlineBackend.close_figures=False # keep figures open in pyplot

plt.plot([1,2,3])
```

Then in a later cell

```
plt.plot([4,5,6])
```

Suggested reading:

- ['%matplotlib inline' causes error in following code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45341765/matplotlib-inline-causes-error-in-following-code)
- [Manipulate inline figure in IPython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895195/manipulate-inline-figure-in-ipython-notebook)

Comment: Neither A nor B work for me, running the latest VS Code on Windows or on Linux. In the second cell, I just get one line of text output (no figure): [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f00d7c41ae0>]