# Plotting data points onto matplotlib Basemap in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization, matplotlib-basemap

[Link to full code](http://54.193.47.160/PrecipVisualization.html)

I am able to successfully create a Basemap of the US within a Jupyter Notebook complete with shapefile, coloring, and borders in Cell 4.

I am trying to plot many data points onto this Basemap with the following line in Cell 8:

```
m.plot(x, y, marker='o', markersize=data, color='#444444', alpha=0.8, latlon=True)
```

The data gets plotted, but I lose all of my Basemap's formatting and shaping. Effectively, I want Cell 8 overlayed on Cell 4. I suspect I am not plotting these shapes on the same plane.

Additionally, plt.show() gives me nothing. What am I missing?

Comment: have you run "%matplotlib inline" with your import statements in the jupyter notebook?

Comment: Yes, I have. The graphs show up in my jupyter notebook, but separately.

Comment: So, I suspect everything works fine if you put the whole code in one cell, right?! For testing it would be good to have a [mcve] available.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest True, I could have boiled the example down. Both this answer (putting it all in 1 cell) and your below answer (passing axis arguments to basemap) are great solutions. Thank you. I wonder why 1 cell works but splitting cells doesnt. Memory?

Comment: No the reason is that there is no current figure present when plotting in the new cell, such that a new figure is created. You may prevent that from happening as detailed in a new part of my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### A. using a figure instance

The idea can be to explicitely specify the axes to plot to at Basemap creation.

Cell 1:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
m = Basemap(... , ax=ax)
```

Cell 2: `# do other stuff`

Cell 3:

```
# plot to map:
m.plot(...)
```

Cell 4:

```
# state figure object to show figure (when inline backend is in use) 
fig
```

---

Screenshot of example:

[image]

#### B. let pyplot not close figures

The other option would be to let pyplot not close the figures. This is the second option from this answer: [How to overlay plots from different cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45766059/4124317)

```
%config InlineBackend.close_figures=False
```

[image]