# Why plt.get_fignums() returns nothing when runs as a single line in a spyder ipython shell?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, spyder

I know there are "**current figure**" and "**current axes**" in matplotlib but if I run the following code line by line in a spyder ipython console, the "**plt.get_fignums**()" always returns an empty list. If the "current figure" and "current axes" are cleared after each run, why do the **plt.gcf()** and **plt.gca()** still return something? Does that mean matplotlib always keeps a blank figure and axes when initialized? Does it has anything to do with the "interactive mode" of matplotlib?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
print(plt.get_fignums())
print(plt.gcf(),plt.gca())
```

Update:I make the code simpler to demo the problem

Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2019, 15:29:51) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 7.6.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

```
In [1]: runfile('xxx.py', wdir='xxx')

[1]
Figure(432x288) AxesSubplot(0.125,0.125;0.775x0.755)

In [2]: print(plt.get_fignums())
   ...: print(plt.gcf(),plt.gca())
[]
Figure(432x288) AxesSubplot(0.125,0.125;0.775x0.755)

In [6]: plt.figure()
   ...: print(plt.get_fignums())
[1]
<Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>

In [7]: print(plt.get_fignums())
[]
```

Comment: [I cannot reproduce this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBNsq.png). Can you add more details?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I saw your pic but the problem does exist in my environment. I posted the raw response text from my console. Not sure if it is about the ipython version?

Comment: So you don't actually type in the code, but `runfile` it? That would mean that the pyplot state is cleared after the file is completed. In cell [2] you then have a clean new state with no open pyplot figures.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Now I typed the code but it is still the same.

Comment: Wait, maybe [this is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45760693/how-to-overlay-plots-from-different-cells) your problem?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thank you! It works now. It seems there is a lot to read before I can thoroughly understand what's wrong.