# Jupyter new cell erase matplolib figure even when recalled using num identifier

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, ipython

Using Jupyter, i'm facing this issue:

I declare several matplotlib figures in cell 1 with an identifier using `num` attribute
I want to get the figures back in cell 2 but it seems to be erased even when using the identifier.

> **Cell n°1**

```py
for i in range(2):
    plt.figure(i, figsize=(15,5))
    plt.plot([0,1], [0,1])
print(plt.get_fignums())
```

```py
#Output
[0, 1]
```

> **Cell n°2**

```py
print(plt.get_fignums())
```

```py
#Output
[]
```

Can someone explain this behaviour and how to recall my figure from cell n°1 ?

Comment: what happens when you delete the `fig = plt.figure(1)` in cell 2? do you get an error or does it print the first figure?

Comment: It works, but If I have 2 figures declared in cell 1, I would like to access from cell 2 the first figure of cell 1. And I would like to do it not using variable (only identifier), but maybe this is where I lost my mind. In my real case, I instance several figures in a loop so they are not stored in variable.

Comment: I don't know why the `plt.figure(1)` doens't work so i cant help you there, but if this is an option for you: Create the figures individual names for the handles `fig1, `fig2`  or store them in list, so you have all of them and can avoid to recall a previous handle

Comment: I've edited my exemple so the issue behaviour is more explicit.

Comment: Yes, but that is still not a minimal reproducible example. For example, I would just collect each plot in a list or dictionary as I made it so that I can recall any one of them using the `.figure` attribute of the plot later myself. However, I cannot tell if that is compatible with what you have. Similarly, I cannot test with what you have provided if the print is consuming what `plt.get_fignums()` returns (it shouldn't since supposed to return a list) or your backend is closing your figures outside of that cell, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45766059/8508004).